# Reply with "Is Typing" message in Microsoft botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am developing a chatbot using MicrofsoftBotFramework on c#.net and LUIS cognitive services.

I want when user type it should reply as typing or bot is typing..

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation($"Type={activity.Type} Text={activity.Text}");

                if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
                {
                    //await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ContactOneDialog());

                    //Implementation of typing indication
                    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                    Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply("Shuttlebot is typing...");
                    isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);

                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () =>
                    new ExceptionHandlerDialog<object>(new ShuttleBusDialog(), displayException: true));                              
                }
                else
                {
                    HandleSystemMessage(activity);
                }
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
                return response;
            }
```

This code is working also but it says "TYPING" as animation and goes to next message. But I want it should show my message which I have set as "Shuttlebot is typing...

[image: see the image here]"

Answer (score 6):

Most of the channels natively support "Is Typing" notifications.  Just send the Typing Activity as a message:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply(String.Empty);
reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
await activityContext.SendResponse(reply);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send the 'typing' status from the controller, the following may be of some help:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply(String.Empty);
reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

Place the above code before the work your controller is trying to do. i.e.

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
```