# How to add typing indicate in Microsoft Web Chat

Tags: botframework

I'm using Microsoft Bot Platform, with the Web-Chat channel, and I want to add my web-chat typing indicate (...).

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reply with "Is Typing" message in Microsoft botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553491/reply-with-is-typing-message-in-microsoft-botframework)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C# or NodeJS?

C#: Possible duplicate of [Reply with “Is Typing” message in Microsoft botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553491/reply-with-is-typing-message-in-microsoft-botframework)

and this worked for me as well (under MessageController.cs):

```
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply();
            isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
        }
```

NodeJS: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-typing-indicator) help?